# asp.net masterpage jQuery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm creating a new web project and i trying to get jQuery working with masterpages

I want to have a link that if it is pressed will do an expansion of a div.

Problem: jQuery isn't fired and the page do a postback

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use ***asp:HyperLink***, instead use just ***a***

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET control IDs are not the same as JavaScript element IDs. ASP.NET modifies IDs before sending them to the client. In your .aspx file's JavaScript, instead of simply `hp1`, specify something like:

```
<%= hp1.ClientID %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set

> ClientIdMode="Static"

if you are using Visual Studio 2010

If not, you can always use a CSS selector like

```
$('.YourControl').click(function(){ alert('hi'); });
```

And in your aspx

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="yourId" cssClass="YourControl" />
```